# Magento - Group Product not Working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to add new Group product in magento. I am able to add it but when i try to edit group products ( when i click on Associated Products ) section not loading. I mean I am not able to edit products under group products and I am able to see products on frontend but then when I click on product to see all description of group product, it shows me "Processing Error "

[image]

is there any one help me.

Comment: You can post Magento questions on their own [se] site: [magento.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go under the admin section and click on system->index management and then re-index all magento indexes.

Please also check the logs into magento code at following location:-
magento-root-directory/var/log/

Comment: in log file i can see this :

#29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:109:"/magento/index.php/admin/catalog_product/superGroup/id/3722/key/d38eb35ad2a6e75ac8b31bc48eff779d/?isAjax=true";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}

Comment: Can you post the full log file(system.log and exception.log) on my email id, so I can help you 
EmailId:- saurabh.chaudhary23sep@gmail.com

Comment: i already solve problem this problem was because of database.. i clean database... may be when we start this problem lots of time we delete categories and products ( with TURNCATE ) so some foreign keys or some id's also deleted... what i did i just install new magento then export all content in new database works fine.
thanks for help ( before i also use database comparision tool but nothing comes out ) now working fine...